# JavaをHTMLの入れ込み

Tags: java, html

こんにちは、HTMLとJavaでウェブサイトを作りたいのですが、
HTMLのコードとJavaのコードを連携してウェブサイトを作ることは可能でしょうか？
インターネットなどであるテンプレートをコピペして使ってみましたが、あまりうまく作動しませんでした。
誰かわかる方いたらお願いします。

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSPでHTMLを出力</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: サーバサイドのJavaとクライアントサイドのHTMLのコードを連携するというのがよくわかりませんでした。基本的にはJavaがHTMLを出力するものです。こういった質問が出てくる時点でまだまだ初学者とみうけられますが、わからないことをQAサイトで質問するよりも書籍やオンライン講習等を用いて体系的に学んだほうがよろしいかと思います。

Comment: 具体的にはどんな Java のコードを実行したいのか、既に試したなら "あまりうまくいかない" ではなく結果を詳しく、参照したページがあるならそれらを質問に含める等しておくと回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問のコメントにもある通り、本来JavaがHTMLを出力するものです。
ですので、質問を編集することをおすすめします。

JSP (Jakarta Server Pages) は、HTTPサーバー上で動く**Javaの**ものです。